# math function in scipy.weave

Tags: performance, scipy, inline

I'd like to make the weave version of this double loop:

```
for i in range(len(x_array)):
    for j in range(N_iter):
        x_array[i] = sin(x_array[i])
```

But how do I deal with arrays and the sine function?

Comment: FYI: weave is no longer part of scipy.  It was removed from scipy 0.19.0.

Comment: I know, but I have some legacy code that has weave in other parts. So for that program, I'd like to stick with weave.